# Matching parameters base on generic types with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I'm looking for a way to make a mock function return different values based on the generic type of its parameter. E.g, if the parameter is any instance of `Generic<Foo>` do something, and if the parameter is any instance of `Generic<Bar>` do something else.

I thought I'll be able to acomplish that using the following code:

```
@Mock
private Getter getter;

@Rule
public final Mocks mocks = new Mocks(this);

@Test
public void testSearch(){
    doReturn("Foo<Boolean>").when(getter).getValue(Matchers.<Foo<Boolean>>any());
    doReturn("Foo<String>").when(getter).getValue(Matchers.<Foo<String>>any());
    System.out.println(getter.getValue(new Foo<Boolean>()));
    System.out.println(getter.getValue(new Foo<String>()));
}

public static class Foo<T> {
}

public class Getter {
    <T> String getValue(BumapinRefOdsHandlerTest.Foo<T> foo) {
        return "not-used";
    }
}
```

However the code prints

```
Foo<String>
Foo<String>
```

What is the correct way to match parameters base on generic type?

Comment: before you record the mock object,fill the getValue method in the Getter class to fulfill your requirement.  if you cannot do it, why should mockito support it.so replace the [return "not-used" ]. technically you can not do this

Comment: During runtime, Mockito has no chance to know, whether Foo<Boolean> or Foo<String> was passed in. Check "type erasure": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do this. During runtime, the type `Foo<Boolean>` and `Foo<String>` will be reduced to the same type `Foo` due to erasure. Eg the following assertion will hold

```
assert new Foo<Boolean>().getClass().equals(new Foo<String>().getClass())
```

There is no way to test a basic generic class for the type parameter used during compile, *unless the class is a subclass and it can be inferred from the class definition, or it is fully specified in the method signature. eg*

```
// Using reflection can recover that FooBoolean used type parameter Boolean
class FooBoolean extends Foo<Boolean> { ... }
// Using reflection on the Method can recover the type parameter of foo
void something(Foo<Boolean> foo) { ... }
```

Comment: TIL. I thought that generics in Java works similarly to templates in C++. I.e, the compiler generates a separate class definition for each generic instance. After reading about erasures it makes perfectly sense.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are not directly available at runtime. And in your case

```
doReturn("Foo<Boolean>").when(getter).getValue(Matchers.<Foo<Boolean>>any());
doReturn("Foo<String>").when(getter).getValue(Matchers.<Foo<String>>any());
```

will end up stubbing the method call with any parameter of type `Foo`. So the last stub wins, in your case `doReturn("Foo<String>")`.

If you reverse the order to

```
doReturn("Foo<String>").when(getter).getValue(Matchers.<Foo<String>>any());
doReturn("Foo<Boolean>").when(getter).getValue(Matchers.<Foo<Boolean>>any());
```

the output will be

```
Foo<Boolean>
Foo<Boolean>
```

Comment: "Generics are available only at compile time" This is not true. The generic type parameters used in method signatures can be recovered, as well as the values used in class definitions.

Comment: @flakes, additional question, can we retrieve those generic type information using byte code engineering tool like (BCEL) at runtime?

Comment: You can use the built in java reflection libs See [getParameterizedType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getParameterizedType--)

Comment: @flakes agreed, shouldn't have used such a blanket statement, but what I meant was in the context of this example, it's not possible to get generic type at runtime. Updated the answer accordingly.